# ioctl HDIO_GET_IDENTITY fails on USB storage devices

Tags: python, usb, device, ioctl, hard-drive

I am trying to get the identity of a USB Hard Drive connected through a SATA-to-USB adapter. The little program I wrote is in Python and uses this:

```
def getID(dev):
    HDIO_GET_IDENTITY = 0x030d
    with open(dev, 'r') as fd:
        buf = fcntl.ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, ' ' * 512)
        fields = struct.unpack_from(struct_hd_driveid, buf)
        serial_no = fields[10].strip()
        fw_rev = fields[14].strip()
        model = fields[15].strip()
    return (serial_no, fw_rev, model)
```

Method I found [here](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2012/02/ata-commands-in-python.html)

The method runs successfully on my internal HDD but I get a

```
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

when running it on my USB connected HDD.

I couldn't find anything related to this - I assume that the operation code may be different for USB connected HDDs....

I almost forgot to say that I am running this from Ubuntu

```
Linux dragosmc-Lenovo-V570 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks,
dragosmc.

Answer (score 2):

HDIO_GET_IDENTITY seems to be IDE/ATA specific.

Mass storage abstracts the ATA device into a SCSI device, so you should have a look to:

- udev
- sg3-utils / libsg3
- sysfs (under linux)
- more complicated scsi command

See [Get vendor name of SCSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441175/get-vendor-name-of-scsi)